# How get value of firebaseArray items

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I try  this code to log  the information of each item in my firebaseArray :

```
  $scope.events = $firebaseArray(ref.child('event').orderByChild('uid').equalTo(Auth.$getAuth().uid));
  $scope.events.$loaded( function(snapshot){
   console.log(snapshot.val()); 
  })
```

I get this error: `snapshot.val is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Angular 1.2 seems to have this problem with firebaseArray. I also had the same problem and upgrading angular to 1.4.5 did the trick for me. you can also try:  [refered link](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/622).